# How to set X-Forwarded-For in PHP to sent client IP with simplexml_load_file

Tags: php

We have got the client real IP behind the proxy using X-Forwarded-For.

But now the issue is that when we are calling a web service using simplexml_load_file, the server hosting the web service gets the IP of our server and not the real client server.

So we need a way to set the IP in X-Forwarded-For header so that the webservice gets the IP of the client that means it will feel that the client IP has called the webservice.

Comment: So just set an HTTP header in the request you make. How to do that exactly depends on how exactly you make the request. This is not guaranteed to work though. Any server in its right mind will ignore the X-Forwarded-For header.

Comment: no this doesn't worked though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One possibility would be to start using [`curl`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php) for communication with the web service, so that you'd be able to set the header value

```
$ip = '123.123.123.123'; // your client's IP Address
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("REMOTE_ADDR: $ip",
                                            "X_FORWARDED_FOR: $ip"));
```

Comment: HTTP is not required only **X_FORWARDED_FOR** worked



`curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("REMOTE_ADDR: $ip",
                                            "X_FORWARDED_FOR: $ip")); `

Comment: For me it was X-FORWARDED-FOR

Comment: `REMOTE_ADDR` is a CGI variable that's set based on the source IP address in the IP layer of the protocol stack. It's not a HTTP header. Setting a header with that name doesn't do anything useful.